# deleting a data in dynamic useref array that references a input file type

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useRef array of input file type, I managed to apply the useRef dynamically by mapping it to the input

```
ref={(el) => (props.rawPageImages.current[index] = { pageNumber, fileRef: el })}
```

so the application works but when I delete one of the mapped input, the input ID's shifts which results to the useRef data unmatched to the mapped input because the arrays in the useRef still points to a different input ID.

edit: here is the mapped input

right now, deleting one page resets the mapped input field ids where the ref array data points to, lets say I have [page1, page2, page3] and I delete page2 but I have a file in page3. I want to have the file in page3 to move to page2 because deleting a page has to make the pageNumbers consistent, im using pageNumbers as GUID because the contents of the page has to match the pageNumber etc, like a book.

Its just that the pageN have different ids and deleting a page resets the ids also which holds files, deleting page2 deletes id2, which makes the previous id3 become id2, but it is id3 that has the files and not id2, so the state and ref are inconsistent

```
const allPages = pages.map((page, i) => {
return (
     <div className="w-full cstm-flex-row gap-2">
        <label className=" cstm-bg-hover cursor-pointer" htmlFor={`filePage${pageNumber}`}>
          <input
            accept="image/*"
            type="file"
            className="hidden peer"
            formNoValidate
            name="pageImage"
            id={`filePage${pageNumber}`}
            onChange={(e) => fileFns.selectedPageImageViewer(pageNumber, e, props.setPages)}
            ref={el => props.rawPageImages.current[index] = {pageNumber, fileRef : el}}
          />

          <BiImage className="scale-150 text-prmColor peer-checked" />
        </label>

        <p className="mr-auto">
          {words > 1 ? "Words" : "Word"}: {words}
        </p>

        <button onClick={() => props.deletePage(pageNumber)ed} type="button" className="cstm-bg-hover">
          <AiFillDelete className="text-prmColor scale-150" />
        </button>
      </div>
          });
```

this is my delete function in the useRef

```
const deleteRawImagePage = (pageNumber) => {
    if (rawPageImages.current) {
      const updatedRawImages = rawPageImages.current.filter((rawImage) => rawImage.pageNumber !== pageNumber);
      console.log(updatedRawImages);
      rawPageImages.current = updatedRawImages;
    }
  };
```

Comment: could you elaborate the answer, i want to know where you get the ref after deleting it

Comment: thank you for reaching out, i just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround, I wanted to use useRef as an alternative to my useState, however, the rerenders messes the useRefs references to the ids because the useRef array still holds id that were supposed to be deleted, but managing the deletion is easier in useState because of the filter function while still maintaining the matching selected files even when the changed order of mapped inputs.

What I did is pass the input's id to the function that the remove button handles then use document.getElementById.

passing of element id

```
<div className="w-full">
      {props.page?.pageImage?.src ? (
        <FilePreview
          purpose="Page Image"
          name={props.page?.pageImage?.name}
          src={props.page?.pageImage?.src}
          clearFiles={() => fileFns.removeSelectedPageImage(pageNumber, props.setPages, `filePage${pageNumber}`)}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
```

delete function

```
export const removeSelectedPageImage = (pageNumber, setState, elementId) => {
  const element = document?.getElementById(elementId);

  if (element) {
    element.value = null;
  }

  setState((prev) =>
    prev.map((p) => {
      if (p.pageNumber === pageNumber) {
        return {
          ...p,
          pageImage: { src: null, name: null },
          rawPageImage: null,
        };
      }
      return p;
    })
  );
};
```

a bit scuffed for now because instead of using a hook I'm using a global function.